# Enemies are Exploding on my Soldiers

Tags: xcom-2

Which enemies explode when they die, how much damage do they do, and what is the blast radius?

Sometimes after a Sectopod explodes, a nearby soldier has the "missed" message show up next to them. How does an explosion miss?

Comment: Sectopods and Gatekeepeers will explode when they die, though I'm not sure what the exact blast radius is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Gatekeeper

A Gatekeeper's death explosion has a radius of "4.5 meters", which I'm fairly sure corresponds to 3 tiles in game, from other conversions I've seen. It deals 5 damage to everything in that radius, which is mitigated by armor (but up to 2 of that armor can be shredded). It cannot crit.

### The Sectopod

A Sectopod's death explosion is.. exactly the same as a Gatekeeper. For some reason it's defined in such a way that all of the same variables are used in both places, meaning if you adjust `GATEKEEPER_DEATH_EXPLOSION_BASEDAMAGE` or `GATEKEEPER_DEATH_EXPLOSION_RADIUS_METERS` in the ini files, it'll change the values for both enemies!

### Missing explosions

I have absolutely no idea why this happens, though I've seen it on my own soldiers multiple times. Having looked through the associated code, every comment states that explosions will be a 100% hit. Perhaps it's a bug, or maybe it's another way that the game cheats on your behalf. Hopefully someone else can identify the cause here.

Comment: On missing my guess (purely from a game mechanics theory point of view, I have no idea about this game) is that if a soldier is on the blast radius (ie half in and half out) it might make a roll to determine whether it hits or not. Its the only thing I can think of.

Comment: The Untouchable skill will make explosions "miss" soldiers.

Comment: @Chris I've looked at the to-hit code for explosions and it basically says "set hit rate to 100%, all the time". This is why I'm so confused by it.

Comment: @SableDreamer That is a great point. Immunity effects could be why this happens, but I can't prove it currently. Might be worth an answer if you're inclined.

Comment: I'm accepting this despite not addressing missed explosions. I'm assuming the Untouchable suggestion from comments is correct.